How to control text wrapping in MAUI
Let's say I have a label and the following string of characters:

The quick, brown fox, jumps over, the lazy dog

What is the way to set the text wrapping behavior so that every piece of text between 2 commas should be kept together (in other words, should be considered as a word)?
So for example if the line breaks at the "z", the rendered result would be:

The quick, brown fox, jumps over,


the lazy dog

How do one achieve this in XAML ?

You can use String.Split to achieve this.

The only way that comes to mind is splitting the text into chunks, then using a FlexLayout with Labels where the LineBreakMode is set to NoWrap and MaxLines is set to 1. You won't be able to achieve this with a single Label, unless you specify the line breaks yourself using \n.


What is the way to set the text wrapping behavior so that every piece
of text between 2 commas should be kept together (in other words,
should be considered as a word)?

You can first use method String.Split to split a long string into an array of strings.
Please refer to the following code:
    private void OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = mLabel.Text; //The quick, brown fox, jumps over, the lazy dog

        string[] subs = str.Split(',');

        foreach (var sub in subs)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Substring: {sub}");
        }
    }


How do one achieve this in XAML ?

To achieve this, a simple method is to add the split strings into different labels, and then add the labels to FlexLayout dynamically.
Please refer to the following code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp521.MainPage">

        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25">

            <Label x:Name="mLabel"
                   Text="The quick, brown fox, jumps over, the lazy dog"  WidthRequest="260"
                 />

        <ScrollView>
            <FlexLayout x:Name="flexLayout"   BackgroundColor="Yellow"  Margin="60"
                        Wrap="Wrap"
                        JustifyContent="Start"  />
        </ScrollView>

        <Button
                Text="Click me"
                Clicked="OnClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>

In xaml.cs, do as follows:
    private void OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = mLabel.Text; //The quick, brown fox, jumps over, the lazy dog

        string[] subs = str.Split(',');
       
        for (int i = 0; i < subs.Length; i++)
        {
            string sub = subs[i];

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"-----> Substring: {sub}");

            Label label = new Label();

            if (i != subs.Length - 1)
            {
                label.Text = sub + ",";
            }
            else
            {
                label.Text = sub;
            }

            flexLayout.Children.Add(label);
        }
    }

Note:
For more information about FlexLayout, please check document: FlexLayout.

Hi @Toto, have you tried to use String.Split to achieve this function?
